# inner join for a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do a sql query and have some problems:

1. I want to select from table_1 the ID's Where parent_id is the value I have:

   ```
   SELECT ID 
     FROM table_1 
    WHERE parent_ID = 'x'
   ```
2. I want to use the ID'S I got in 1. and

   ```
   SELECT 
     FROM table_2 
    WHERE ID = 'The ID's from Query 1.'
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved with the use of `IN` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table_1 WHERE parent_ID = 'x')
```

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
select ...
  from table_1 a
  join table_2 b on(a.id = b.id)
 where a.parent_id = 'x';
```

**Edit**
Note: the query will potentially produce duplicate rows depending on the keys and relation between the tables. For example, you will get duplicates if, for a given `table_1.parent_id = X`, there can be multiple occurrences of the same `table_1.ID`. 
Another example is when table_2.ID isn't unique.

In those cases you would want to remove the duplicates (using distinct, group by, partitioned @row_number, etc) **or**, not produce the duplicates in the first place using a semi-join instead (exists, in). Have a look @OMG Ponies answer for reference.

Comment: +1 Glad at least one answer has a join instead of an inner select.

Comment: @Galz: But this will return duplicates if there are more than TABLE_1 record relating to a TABLE_2 record.  JOINs are not always the answer - you have to test the output to make sure the results are correct.

Comment: well he asked for a join didn't he? ;-)

Comment: This is the answer closest to the one being asked for (OP was looking for a join), though I think most people would probably opt to use a subquery/subselect

Comment: @sbook: I don't see any mention of a JOIN in the original post, and there's at least three ways of getting the result in SQL.  All three operate differently.  Just because people "opt", doesn't make it right...

Comment: As for the duplicates (or what relations the tables have), that is really the OP's responsibility to tell. We can't possibly give answers for all permutations of a problem. Throwing distinct at a SQL statement just in case is wrong. Also, MySQL's optimizer isn't sofisticated enough to remove unnecessary distinct operations (even on primary key).

Comment: @Ronnis: I'm not recommending DISTINCT "just in case" - it's a fact that multiple child records will produce duplicate parent records when using a JOIN.  We don't know the data, so why you assume the best of the situation?  It used to be I'd get slammed for not address the issue, and now I watch others get to dismiss the fact.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, I feel your pain, trust me :) But I'm not dismissing it, I'm laying it in the hands of the OP. I'm sick and tired of troubleshooting performance with queries using distinct and only outer joins when none are needed. In fact, in all too many cases it hides modeling problems, data quality issues, lack of understanding of SQL, or even lack of understanding  the data model used. My motto is: make deliberate and explicit choices and fail loud and spectacularily when your assumptions are wrong. Point taken though, I'll update the answer with a warning.

Answer (score 4):

### Using IN

```
SELECT t2.*
  FROM TABLE_2 t2
 WHERE t2.id IN (SELECT t1.id
                   FROM TABLE_1 t1
                  WHERE t1.parent_id = 'x')
```

### Using EXISTS

```
SELECT t2.*
  FROM TABLE_2 t2
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM TABLE_1 t1
                WHERE t1.id = t2.id
                  AND t1.parent_id = 'x')
```

### Using an INNER JOIN

The `DISTINCT` (or GROUP BY) is necessary to eliminate duplicates if there are more than one records in TABLE_1 that relate to a record in TABLE_2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.*
  FROM TABLE_2 t2
  JOIN TABLE_1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
                 AND t1.parent_id = 'x'
```

Comment: This one has all of the options :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_2 where id in (select id from table_1 where parent_id = 'x')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's better to you use this:

```
SELECT [value]
  FROM [table2]
 WHERE [value] IN (SELECT [value] 
                     FROM [table1]
                    WHERE [value] = "[value]"
                  )
```